# Is there anyway to get a Rest service call to return a plain String?

Tags: java, javascript, spring, rest

I am writing a Rest service that checks to see if any providers are ingesting. If so return true and if not return false. I wouldn't mind if it returned a boolean but I couldn't find anything about it when doing research. This is the javascript that calls the rest service in a ajax call:

```
 var result = $.ajax({url:cdpeConfig.providerUrl+'/updateStatus',type: 'GET'});
  if (result=="true"){
        alert(result);
      }
  else{
        alert(JSON.stringify(result));
      }
```

the json.stringify is the only way I have been able to see what it returns. All I have seen it return is `{"readyState":1}`
Here is the java:

```
`@GET
@Path("/updateStatus")
@Produces({MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN})
public String isIngesting(){
    String result = "false";
    List<Provider> providers = new ArrayList<Provider>();
    providers = providerManager.getAllProviders();
    for (Provider provider : providers) {
        if (provider.getUpdateStatus().toLowerCase().equals(CdpeEnum.UpdateStatus.INGEST.toString().toLowerCase()) ) {
            result = "true";
        }
    }
    return result;
}`
```

Comment: try doing console.log(result) in your javascript code. It's much better way to visualize data than alert... And of course less annoying too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var result = $.ajax({url:cdpeConfig.providerUrl+'/updateStatus',type: 'GET'});

result.done(function(data){
    alert(data);
});
```

done method is the success function in jquery ajax. It will execute once your request is completed.

Comment: haha awesome! I had been researching for a few hours trying different things, next time as soon as I get stuck I am posting a question. Thanks!